# AppArmor failing to start

Tags: opensuse, apparmor

I'm trying to start AppArmor in an openSUSE 11.4 system. I run:

`rcapparmor start`

and I always get this error:

`Starting AppArmor Loading AppArmor module                  failed`

Is there any log file I can check to get more info about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `Loading AppArmor module failed` message suggests that it's the kernel that threw the fault. In that case, interesting information is likely being sent to the kernel ring-buffer. You can get at that with `dmesg | tail -20` for the last 20 lines. It'll also likely get dumped to `/var/log/messages` as well.